# Which encryption algorithms will be used to replace RSA when quantum computers become common?

Tags: cryptography, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are the encryptions "broken" with great computing power?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/are-the-encryptions-broken-with-great-computing-power)

I just wondered which algorithms will be used once quantum computers become common. Are there already existing algorithms that don't rely on factorization problems and thus could replace RSA when the age of quantum computers starts?

Comment: Have a quick look at http://security.stackexchange.com/q/4286/485 as well - John and Thomas both list algorithms which are resistant.

Answer (score 8):

The eminent programmer and cryptographer Daniel J. Bernstein has a [page](http://pqcrypto.org/) dedicated to that.  The shortest version:

Hash trees, NTRU, McEliece, and multivariate-quadratic systems.

McEliece, for example, is immune to quantum speedups because it [relies on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McEliece_cryptosystem) "the hardness of decoding a general linear code (which is known to be NP-hard[4])." Since [NP is not in BQP](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo%3aB#bqp), NP-hard problems remain hard; even with practical quantum computers.

Comment: Would you please quote the important parts of the site in your answer?

Answer (score 5):

NIST did a [survey of Quantum Resistant Public Key Cryptography](http://middleware.internet2.edu/idtrust/2009/papers/07-perlner-quantum.pdf). Quote:

> Of the various lattice based cryptographic schemes that have been
>   developed, the NTRU family of cryptographic algorithms [25, 26, 27]
>   appears to be the most practical.

There is an open source implementation of NTRU at http://ntru.sf.net/.

Another algorithm worth mentioning is the signature scheme GMSS for which there is also an open source implementation.

Other quantum resistant algorithms like McEliece suffer from the fact that key sizes are in the 100's of kbytes or more.